# remove space and add comma in python

Tags: python

Here is my code:

```
import fileinput


input_file = 'in.txt'
output = open('out.txt', 'w+')


for each_line in fileinput.input(input_file):
    output.write(x.strip() for x in each_line.split(','))
```

I get "expect character buffer" as the error. I am not sure what is the best way to go about this? I am trying to remove all tabs and spaces and replace them with a comma.

edit: forexample my data looks like:

```
1   2335    mike

1   4089    doug
```

and I want to turn it into

```
1,2335,mike noll

1,4089,doug funny
```

edit, i only want to remove the first 2 spaces in the first 2 columns

Comment: `x.strip() for x in each_line.split(',')` evaluates to a generator (which you can turn into a list by surrounding with `[]`s) but `write()` does not accept a generator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`x.strip() for x in each_line.split(',')` does returns a generator object (not a string buffer that is expected by the `output.write`)

You can do:

```
with open('out.txt', 'w+') as output:
    for each_line in fileinput.input(input_file):
        output.write("\n".join(x.strip() for x in each_line.split(',')))
```

Comment: It returns generator object indeed

Answer (score 0):

Use `str.join` to join the list into a string and then write it to the file.

In your code you're actually passing a genexp to `file.write`.

```
for each_line in fileinput.input(input_file):
    output.write(" ".join(x.strip() for x in each_line.split(',')) +'\n')
```

**Update:**

```
with open('out.txt', 'w') as f:
    for line in fileinput.input('input.txt'):
        line = line.split(None,2)
        f.write(','.join(line))
```

Comment: How would I save it into a file? instead of printing it?

Comment: open a file `x = open('filename','w')` then just add a `x.write(...)` around what is after the print